# difference between embedded opc ua server/client and normal opc ua server/client

Tags: embedded, opc-ua

Can you please tell me what is the difference between the embedded opc ua and normal opc ua.
Actually i have search over internet but dint able to find the exact difference

if anyone knows???

Answer (score 1):

If you approach from OPC UA Profiles point of view, then look at this web site: [OPC UA Profiles](https://opcfoundation-onlineapplications.org/profilereporting)

It contains what exactly should support Embedded UA Server vs Standard UA Server.

Answer (score 0):

Embedded OPC UA server runs in a device such as a PLC (Programmable Logic Controller), smart sensor, IoT gadget or so.

"Normal" OPC UA server runs on a PC or comparable general-purpose computer.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what profiles a server is required to implement. Most likely, an embedded OPC UA Server will support less of the specified functionality. (site quoted by @ravil has moved: [OPC foundation profiles](https://apps.opcfoundation.org/ProfileReporting/))

Some characteristic differences: supported security policies, required amount of supported parallel sessions, continuation points per session, ... So mostly stuff that relates to the limited resources typical for an embedded environment.